# Integration with OneNote 2016 desktop version

Tags: ms-office

We tried to manage the authentication in federated mode via WS-Federation protocol. In this case it seems that OneNote includes,  Internet Explorer 7  browser to redirect the user towards the passive endpoint of STS, instead of the active endpoint, do you why ?

We’re working also on a connection of our application via ADFS, and we’ve done it thru the passive endpoint of ADFS.     
Should we use the active endpoint ADFS ? Why this is not the solution for OneNote ?

In standard cases the authentication is based on usage of browser Web storage that is supported only from IE8 . Why is it so?

Thanks

Eric Vernié

Answer (score 0):

Office SharePoint where you are storing OneNote uses MSOFBA protocol which is a passive protocol that transitions to WS-Fed via a browser dialog. This is different in SPO and potentially different in some future updates to SP2016.

Thanks
//Sam